# URIs to log in on VS Code don't work on Vivaldi

Tags: linux, github, visual-studio-code, manjaro, vivaldi

I'm on Manjaro KDE, using Vivaldi browser, and VS Code from Snap.

To log in to things like Sync Settings on VS Code, it opens your browser to a page where you can log in to GitHub, and it then tries to open a magnetic URI with VS Code, containing the generated tokens.

Since I moved to Manjaro, this never worked for me, but before, prior to trying to open the magnetic URI, the web page showed you the URI and allowed you to copy-paste it manually back into VS Code, and that's what I used to do, and it worked fine.

Now, that option seems to be gone, and it logged me out of basically everything on VS Code.

What happens is the following:

1. Go to "Sign in to Sync Settings"
   [image: Sign in to Sync Settings]
2. "Sign in with GitHub"
   [image: Sign in with GitHub]
3. Page opens on browser, prompting to "Open xdg-open"
   [image: Open xdg-open]
4. Another instance of VS Code appears, "Visual Studio Code - URL Handler"
   [image: Visual Studio Code - URL Handler]
5. This remains loading for a while
   [image: Signing in to github.com...]
6. And then it says "Cancelled"
   [image: Cancelled]

The same happens whenever I try to log in on the other options, Copilot and Live Share.

System info:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.91.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.28-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2
```

VS Code info:

```
Version: 1.66.1
Commit: 8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898
Date: 2022-04-06T14:51:26.173Z
Electron: 17.2.0
Chromium: 98.0.4758.109
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.11-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.28-1-MANJARO snap
```

Edit: It seems that using Chromium as a default browser worked, so this issue is likely related to Vivaldi somehow.